# Library for video resampling

Tags: video, signal-processing, frame-rate

Audio resampling is a common operation, and there are lots of high-quality libraries available. Some of them, like `libsamplerate`, even allow the resampling factor to change through time.

I want to perform the same process with video frames (i.e. changing the FPS). Right now, I'm aware of the following filters in FFMPEG:

- [`fps`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps-1), which seems to be a simple zero-order hold and doesn't allow for variable factors.
- [`framestep`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-framestep), which just drops frames much like a zero-order hold.
- [`framerate`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framerate), which seems to be a linear interpolator. Again, it doesn't allow for variable factors.

I've also come across [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4853/best-way-to-resample-a-signal-image) which explains how to design such a filter (the `fftfilt` filter in FFMPEG could be useful?).

Does anybody know of any option for proper, programmatical video resampling?

Comment: I assume it should take an encoded video as input, decode the frames, change framerate (using interpolation or whatever) and re-encode again? Is this kind of scenario you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is the scenario I'll using it for. My question only asks for options to do the interpolation, though, so generic answers would be preferred.

Comment: I ended up using a [zero-order hold](https://gist.github.com/jmendeth/6eecd7e694070f5c684363fc48d1db9e) to do the timelapse for now.